# Get only two values of multiple Checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I found this code on codeLAB and I'm trying to get true result only if "Cricket" and "Boxing" are checked. Currently it works if both of them are checked, but also when the others are selected.

https://jsfiddle.net/kubus1234/oksm8eaw/

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var favorite = [];
  $.each($("input[name='sport']:checked"), function() {
    favorite.push($(this).val());
  });
  var test = [];
  $.each($("input[name='sport']:checked"), function() {
    test.push($(this).val());
  });
  if (favorite[1] == "cricket" || test[1] == "boxing") {
    alert("Your are the best");
  } else {
    alert("Your are looser");
  }
});
```

Any solution?

Comment: For one, arrays in JS are zero indexed, so they start at `["one", "two"][0] === "one"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you traversed the selected checkboxes twice, but here's one way to get your results:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var selected = $("input[name='sport']:checked").toArray().map(function(checkbox) {
     return $(checkbox).val();
    });
    
    if (selected.length === 2 && selected[0] === "cricket" && selected[1] === "boxing") {
      alert("You are the best");
    } else {
      alert("You lose");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <h3>Select your favorite sports:</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="football" name="sport">Football</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="baseball" name="sport">Baseball</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="cricket" name="sport">Cricket</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="boxing" name="sport">Boxing</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="racing" name="sport">Racing</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="swimming" name="sport">Swimming</label>
  <br>
  <button type="button">Get Values</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @kubus1234 If you found this answer helpful, please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easily researchable but I'll post a solution anyway

1) I gave the checkboxes ids

2) I changed the JavaScript to check if both checkboxes are checked at once with `.is(":checked")`

```
<form>
    <h3>Select your favorite sports:</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkFootball" value="football" name="sport"> Football</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkBaseball" value="baseball" name="sport"> Baseball</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkCricket" value="cricket" name="sport"> Cricket</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkBoxing" value="boxing" name="sport"> Boxing</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkRacing" value="racing" name="sport"> Racing</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkSwimming" value="swimming" name="sport"> Swimming</label>
    <br>
    <button type="button">Get Values</button>
</form>

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        if ($('#chkCricket').is(':checked') && $('#chkBoxing').is(':checked')) {
            alert("Checked");
        }
        else {
            alert("Not checked");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/oksm8eaw/2/

Please don't use javascript alerts. Alerts cause cancer...
... instead use ids, and jQuery `html()`: add this to the HTML:  `<div id="result"></div>`

## Solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        var matchCount = 0;
        $('input').each(function(){
                if( this.value == "cricket" || this.value == "boxing") {
                if(this.checked) matchCount++;
            }
        });

        if(matchCount>1){
            $("#result").html("YUP!");
        } else {
            $("#result").html("NOPE!");
        }
    });
});
```